# Flip a DICOM Image over the x = y Line

Tags: vtk

I am working on displaying a DICOM image. But it requires me to flip the incoming DICOM image about the x = y line. In other words, I want to rotates the image about the x = y axis with 180 degree

I have found setFlipOverOrigin() from vtkImageFlip. However, it seems not working. Could anyone suggest me a method or how to use setFlipOverOrigin() correctly if it helps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: umm... in other words, I want to rotates the image about the x = y axis with 180 degree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `vtkTransform` class, and apply a 180 degrees rotation around the axe (1, 1, 0) => x = y = 1 ; z = 0

```
void vtkTransform::RotateWXYZ   (double angle, double x, double y, double z );
```

> Create a rotation matrix and concatenate it with the current
>   transformation according to PreMultiply or PostMultiply semantics. The
>   angle is in degrees, and (x,y,z) specifies the axis that the rotation
>   will be performed around.

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform> rotation = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform>::New();
rotation->RotateWXYZ (180, 1.0, 1.0, 0);
// rotation->setInputConnection( DicomReaderImage->GetOutputPort () ); // link your image into your pipeline
rotation->Update ();
```